# WordPress creating 404s under blog tags

Tags: pagination, urls

Webmaster Tools is pulling up 404s under by blog tags. I go to a blog tag, scroll all the way down and find an "older posts" button. I click the button and the new page is a 404 because there is not enough content under that specific tag to run into a second page.

How do I prevent wordpress from automatically creating these /page/2/ ?

Comment: can you change the limit in wordpress settings -> Blog pages show at most? ... try 5.

Comment: What do your permalink settings look like? Did you flush the rewrite rules? Is your .htaccess _working_ as expected? Is this a custom query? What template is being used? Questions, questions, questions...